# Unchecked Input for Loop Condition - CheckMarx error for LocalDate

Tags: java, validation, secure-coding, checkmarx

```
    public List<ExchangeRate> getExchangeRate(@RequestBody @Validated ExchangeRateRequest exchangeRateRequest) {
        LocalDateTime conversionDateTime = parseConversionDateTime(exchangeRateRequest.getConversionDateTime());
        List<ExchangeRate> exchangeRateList = service.getExchangeRates(exchangeRateRequest, conversionDateTime);
        return exchangeRateList;
    }

    private LocalDate getPreviousBusinessDate(LocalDateTime conversionDateTime) {
        ZonedDateTime localConversionDateTimeWithZone = ZonedDateTime.of(conversionDateTime, ZoneOffset.systemDefault());
        ZonedDateTime conversionDateTimeAtUtc = localConversionDateTimeWithZone.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        LocalDate currentUtcDate = conversionDateTimeAtUtc.toLocalDate();
        LocalDate prev = currentUtcDate.minusDays(1);
        while(prev.getDayOfWeek()==DayOfWeek.SUNDAY || prev.getDayOfWeek()==DayOfWeek.SATURDAY) {
            prev = prev.minusDays(1);
        }
        return prev;
    }

public class ExchangeRateRequest {
    private final String conversionDateTime;

    @Valid
    private final List<ExchangeRateCurrency> currencies;

    @JsonCreator
    public ExchangeRateRequest(@JsonProperty("conversionDateTime") String conversionDateTime,
                               @JsonProperty("currencies") List<ExchangeRateCurrency> currencies) {
        this.conversionDateTime = conversionDateTime;
        this.currencies = currencies;
    }
}
```

The element *exchangeRateRequest* flows through the code without being validated, and is eventually used in a loop condition in getPreviousBusinessDate of ExchangeRateService.java. This constitutes an Unchecked Input for Loop Condition.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Maybe you can share the ExchangeRateRequest class details as well?

Answer (score 0):

I think this case is *False Positive* and you have nothing to do (except to ask to your *Checkmark* owner to ignore this result.

The *Unchecked Input for Loop Condition* means that the loop might run unexpectedly because the condition is not sanitized.

For example, if you have hard calculation in a loop, and for example you expect to get a *day of week* from the user to run your calculation on the next rest days of the week, the user can give you the number 8, and you will get infinite loop.

**In your case**, the *loop condition* is not a **range**, but it is just checking specific state, and if it's not in this state, the code will continue.

I can't see any case for something bad that can be happened.